# not enough storage is available to process this command in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to write a multi-thread program in visual studio (c++). I get this error message when I increase the number of one active class. Is there any way I can get around this problem? I mean should I change some of the setup or should I do something to my code?

Comment: more information needed. post the offending code.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/OutOfMemoryException+Fix